# asp.net generating thumbnails "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Tags: asp.net, thumbnails, system.drawing

im using asp.net system.drawing in order to generate a thumbnail after the image finish uploading using this code:

```
//programmImages -- the id of the fileupload control

string path = "~/User/" + "progimgs/" + programmImages.FileName;
string thumbPath = "~/User/" + "thums/" + programmImages.FileName;

programmImages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
programmImages.Dispose();

//generating the tumbnails
System.Drawing.Image thum = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(path));

System.Drawing.Image createTumb = 
                           thum.GetThumbnailImage(250, 140, ()=>false, IntPtr.Zero);

createTumb.Save(thumbPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

im getting this erro "A generic error occurred in GDI+"

on this line "createTumb.Save(thumbPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);"

what is the problem, thanks.

Comment: Dont you see that the thumbPath is not a valid path ?

Comment: @Aristos - im sry i don't see it, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Aristos pointed out i was missing the server.mappath from the thumbPath.

Comment: I just had the same issue while trying to save a thumbnail as well.

Comment: @reaper_unique - if the problem still persist post your code.

Comment: Oh, hehe, what I meant was that I forgot Server.MapPath() as well, adding it solved it for me as well ;)

Comment: @reaper_unique - I thought as much, but was just making sure.